# hibernate session get returns null

Tags: hibernate, session, get

My hibernate query returns null. I did search on the internet but could not find an answer for this specific question. Here is the query:

```
public T findById(Long id){
    return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(getPersistentClass(), id);
}
```

The entity with the id exists in the database, but this query always return null and I don't know why. Here is the generated query:

```
Hibernate: select quiz0_.QUIZ_ID as QUIZ1_3_0_, quiz0_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY3_0_, quiz0_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED3_3_0_, quiz0_.CREATOR_ID as CREATOR4_3_0_, quiz0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT5_3_0_, quiz0_.IS_IMMEDIATE_CORRECTION as IS6_3_0_, quiz0_.IS_MULTIPAGE as IS7_3_0_, quiz0_.NUM_OF_QUESTIONS as NUM8_3_0_, quiz0_.IS_PRACTICE_MODE as IS9_3_0_, quiz0_.TITLE as TITLE3_0_, quiz0_.IS_RANDOM as IS11_3_0_, quiz0_.RATING as RATING3_0_ from QUIZ quiz0_ where quiz0_.QUIZ_ID=?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made sure, through debugging, that "id" is valid?

Comment: The problem was actually in the calling method, which was returning null. Anyways. Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the following to make sure the class is set when this dao implementation is extended and used (not a complete dao implementation)

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T, I extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, I>{
        private Class<T> type;
        public GenericDaoImpl() {
            this.type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
        public T find(I id) {
            Assert.notNull(id);
            return (T) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(getType(), id);
        }
}
```

Comment: I did the same pattern, except with I did as <T extends serializable> instead of <T, I extends serializable>. Although, I don't see how that might affect the afore-mentioned line of query, as long as the correct Id is passed to sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(getPersistentClass(), id);
.

Comment: That is odd. Is the Quiz class mapped correctly? Have you tried adding debug comments a little everywhere to make sure the right data is being passed?

Answer (score 0):

if your database table `QUIZ` mapped to `T` class

try `T.class` instead of `getPersistentClass()`

or you can change `T.class` with your entity name

Comment: T.class does not work, I think because T won't be available at runtime. It seems that getPersistentClass() is not the problem as shown in query. It does identify the correct type.